# LongListSelector Scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In my app i load items from server in `LongListSelector`. On my search page i have an app bar too. I need to decrease its opacity so that it shows the items that hide behind the app bar. When i make my `AppBar` transparent, the long list selector items remain hidden behind the app bar.

I need exactly the same look and feel that is shown in foursquare in below screenshot.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your Root Grid or your LongListSelector Marging work?

```
Margin="0,0,0,75"
```

Like:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,75" />
```

Greetings!

**UPDATE**

I was searching now a little bit on google and I found [this article](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth). I recommend to read it.

In this article I saw that the LongListSelector has a ListFooterTemplate, so you can set a footer and it will work.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="citiesListFooter">
    <Border Background="White" Opacity="0.2" Height="70">
        <TextBlock Text="Cities Footer" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

put it in your MainPage.Resource and after in your LongListSelector put this line of code:

```
ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource citiesListFooter}" Margin="1,0,-1,0"/>
```

This example is from the link I give you above. Hope helps.

greetings!

Comment: no, it decreases overall display area of the longlistselector. What i need is longlistselector items keep showing behind the opaque appbar so that user gets the idea there are more items. When user scrolls down to last item it should show like i have shown in screenshot. Is there anything like footer ?

Comment: mmm ok, have you tried to add at last child a Transparent rectangle?

Comment: heh, well its fine if it works but i don know how to do it, i am using by assigning collection to itemssource so how can i add rectangle? or grid of height 100? how